# Disconnect SignalR User on mvc Idenity Logout

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, signalr, asp.net-identity

I'm tracking how many people are online on the page with signalR.

It updates the List when they login with their user.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Live_Friend_Message_With_SignalR.Models;

namespace Live_Friend_Message_With_SignalR
{
    public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        private static List<Tuple<string, ApplicationUser>> _connectedUsers = new List<Tuple<string, ApplicationUser>>();

        public override Task OnConnected()
        {
            if (Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                using (ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext())
                {
                    var user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(i => i.UserName == Context.User.Identity.Name);

                    if (!_connectedUsers.ToList().Exists(i => i.Item1 == Context.ConnectionId && i.Item2 == user))
                    {
                        _connectedUsers.Add(new Tuple<string, ApplicationUser>(Context.ConnectionId, user));
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (Context.User.Identity.Name == null)
                {
                    OnDisconnected(true);
                }
            }
            Clients.All.Notification(_connectedUsers.Count);
            return base.OnConnected();
        }

        public override Task OnReconnected()
        {
            return base.OnReconnected();
        }

        public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
        {
            if (_connectedUsers.ToList().Exists(i => i.Item1 == Context.ConnectionId))
            {
                _connectedUsers.Remove(_connectedUsers.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Item1 == Context.ConnectionId));
            }
            Clients.All.Notification(_connectedUsers.Count);
            return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried many things to remove an user from the list when they logout, but so far I cant make anything work.

Do anyone have an idea how to do this.

Comment: What's the actual problem?  I do something similar and it works as expected.  It is strange you are calling OnDisconnected from your OnConnected method - what are you expecting there - the client is not disconnected at that point...

Comment: When i use my Logout controller in mvc i Would like it to disconnect the userfrom signalr also, so the person dont get notifications when they are logged out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a method to your `ChatHub` so you can query `ConnectionId` from a user name.  Then do something like this;

**Controller**

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
    private readonly IHubContext<ChatHub> _hubContext;

    public AccountController(
        SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager,
        IHubContext<ChatHub> hubContext)
    {
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _hubContext = hubContext;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> LogOff()
    {
        var connectionid = ChatHub.GetConnectionIdByName(User.Identity.Name);
        await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
        await _hubContext.Clients.Client(connectionId).logoff();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(HomeController.Index), "Home");
    }
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$.connection.chathub.client.logoff = function() {
    $.connection.hub.stop();
}
```